# Linear-gradient() over inline <img> tags

Tags: html, css, css-gradients

I want to create this effects of`linear-gradient` over the images:

[image]

I tried this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNZoeJ

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bg-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://unsplash.it/1200x800') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.bg-img:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002f4b, #dc4225);
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

But my images are inline not background, so that doesn't work.

```
<% review.forEach(function(review) { %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="img">
            <a href="/review/<%= review._id %>"><img src="<%= review.image %>"></a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="caption">
            <a href="/review/<%= review._id %>"><h2><%= review.title %></h2></a>
        </div>

        <span><%= review.created.toDateString(); %></span>

        <div class="relative">
            <p><%- review.body.substring(0,250); %></p>
            <div class="absolute"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
 <% }) %>
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired effect with inline `<img>` tags?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ejs ? is this the image inserted into that link ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`objcet-fit`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) for inline images. It works similarly to `background-size`. Note, it doesn't work on IE and Edge yet.

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bg-img {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.bg-img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.bg-img:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002f4b, #dc4225);
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/1200x800">
</div>
```

Other than that, you may be able to use inline `style="background: ..."` or `<style>...</style>` if the container has known width and height.

**Edit**

I made a simple demo with `<img>` tags like the picture you posted, switch to background images as I mentioned above if you need to support more browsers.

```css
.hero {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}
.hero div {
  position: relative;
}
.hero img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.hero h2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 10px;
}
.a, .b {
  flex: 1;
}
.b {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.b1, .b2 {
  height: 50%;
}
.a:before,
.b1:before,
.b2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002f4b, #dc4225);
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="a">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/600x300?random">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="b1">
      <img src="http://unsplash.it/600x400?random">
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="b2">
      <img src="http://unsplash.it/600x500?random">
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ewh9uu0/)**

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

CSS can do the job.

The pseudo idea seems fine to me, and you should use `pointer-events` to allow click through it.

You can use rgba() colors instead opacity.

You can help yourself with `display:flex` to draw you columns or `float` ...

You can use selectors such `nth-child()` to select first and odd `.thumbnails` (to size and apply different direction for the linear gradient).

You can set the linear background on pseudo'sparent, it will be seen and increased  while image is loading or missing.

You can add an inset shadow to let see some edges on images.

...

example

```css
html,
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.thumbnail:before {
 content: '';
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: inherit;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
 pointer-events: none;
 /* allows to click under it */
}

.box {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 height: 200px;
 width: 600px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow:0 0 0 1px  rgba(0, 125, 255, 1);
}

.box > .thumbnail {
 flex: 1;
 min-height:100px;
 max-height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 max-width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 125, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 125, 0, 0.5));
}

.box > .thumbnail:first-of-type {
 min-height:200px;
 max-height: 200px;
 max-width: 200px;
}

.box > .thumbnail:nth-child(odd) {
 background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 125, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 125, 0, 0.5));
}

.img,
.img a {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.img a img {
 width: 100%;
}


/* demo purpose*/

body {
 display: flex;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="/review/<%= review._id %>">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/1200x800" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="/review/<%= review._id %>">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/1200x802?random" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="/review/<%= review._id %>">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/1200x801?random" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="/review/<%= review._id %>">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/1200x800?random" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="/review/<%= review._id %>">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/1201x799?random" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```